# Asp.net core bind data to button

Tags: jquery, ajax, model, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET Core MVC.
I have this model:

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4096)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool isCompleted { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to bind the `isCompleted` to the button like: when I click that button, it's value will be changed. Currently I'm using Ajax:

```
CompleteTodo = function (id, isCompleted) {
    if (isCompleted === true) {
        var data = "{\n  \"isCompleted\": false,\n}"
    } else {
        var data = "{\n  \"isCompleted\": true,\n}"
    }
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/todos/"+id,
        "method": "PUT",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
        },
        "data": data
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

The problem is, I can't change the button's class after the call, my button tag:

```
<button id="ButtonComplete" href="#" onclick='CompleteTodo(@item.Id,@item.isCompleted.ToString().ToLower())' class="waves-effect waves-light @(item.isCompleted?"blue":"green") btn">@if (!item.isCompleted)
                { <i class="material-icons">done</i>}
                else
                { <i class="material-icons">clear</i> }</button>
```

So how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: "Button value changes but class does not change" do i misunderstand you? Or both don't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use server side binding, button class does not change without refreshing page. Refresh the page when ajax completed:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    location.reload(false);
});
```

Or change class(add/remove) on the client side with javascript.

ps: Make sure after ajax call `item.isCompleted` changes as expected.